# Does Netflix Eureka support dynamically named Spring Boot applications?

Tags: spring-boot, netflix-eureka

Per [this article](https://spring.io/guides/gs/service-registration-and-discovery/) Netflix's Eureka service registry supports registering named services using the property `spring.application.name`.  For example:

```
spring.application.name=a-eureka-client
```

Does Spring-Boot/Eureka support having dynamic names based on perhaps a templating pattern like:

```
spring.application.name=a-eureka-client-####
```

Thus the first two instances deployed would be registered as:

```
 a-eureka-client-0001
 a-eureka-client-0002
```

Comment: I am curious... Once you have your application registered with the unique names. How would you expect another application that wants to call that application? Would you expect that other application to use the full name? What you are asking for seems like a very odd use case.

Comment: I'm thinking about an "Elastic cloud" type scenario where each `a-eureka-client` instance supports accounts and when say `a-eureka-client-0002` is reaching capacity another instance is started and registered as `a-eureka-client-0003`.  The `account-deployment-manager` would then see the new one and start assigning accounts to it.  When the client that needs access to an account it would first look up the server name that holds the account (`eureka-client-0003`) and then look up the coordinates of that instance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could pass `spring.application.name` property via command line or through environment variables as shown below:

`$ java -jar app.jar --spring.applocation.name=a-eureka-client-001`

Or

`$ export SPRING_APPLICATION_NAME=a-eureka-client-002`

`$ java -jar app.jar`

Alternatively, you can come up with a custom property called `my.app.suffix`, inject that as a command line property or environment variable as shown above, and in your `application.properties` (or YML), use the suffix to complete the name of your application:

`spring.application.name: a-eureka-client-${my.app.suffix:some-default}`

That way, you can support a case when the suffix is not provided, in which case `some-default` will be used as the suffix by default.

Answer (score 0):

if you are using spring boot then in src/main/resources folder you have to have extra
**bootstrap.properties** file, and line line below. *Don't put in application.properties file.*

```
spring.application.name=Car-Position-Tracker
```

bootstrap.properties file is read while application context is being loaded: See Reference manual of Spring-cloud

and to be picked up add Build  plugin in POM, which is by ***.properties**

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>

    <resources>
        <resource>
            <filtering>true</filtering>
            <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
            <includes>
                <include>*.properties</include>
            </includes>
        </resource>     
    </resources>        
</build>
```

Answer (score 0):

Apart from command line or through environment variables, it is also possible to set it programmatically in Java when necessary, e.g. automatically append the host's id.

In `<SomeName>Application.java` (or `ServletInitializer.java` when using container like Tomcat):

```java
// ...
public static void main(String[] args) {
        // add this line
        System.setProperty("spring.application.name", "some dynamatically generated name");
        SpringApplication.run(<SomeName>Application.class, args);
```